termux Why can't I run the program on SDcard?
u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hi!");
        return 0;
}
 u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # gcc test.c -o test
u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # ./test
zsh: permission denied: ./test
 ✘ u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # bash ./test
./test: ./test: cannot execute binary file
 ✘ u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # sh ./test
./test: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # mv test ~
 u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # ~/test
Hi!%                                               u0_a238@localhost  ~/storage/external-1 # 

termux Why can't I run the program on SDcard?
Is this Android's responsibility?
Is there any way to get termux to execute the SDcard program?
I want to build some programs from the source code and install them on SDcard
Or install the APK directly on the SDcard
Is there any other way besides root?

Check it's mounted without noexec set

@MarcinOrlowski
Yes, it has the noexec attribute
Does this attribute have to be root to be changed to exec?
u0_a238@localhost  ~ # cat /proc/mounts | grep /storage/sdcard1
/mnt/media_rw/sdcard1 /storage/sdcard1 sdcardfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,fsuid=1023,fsgid=1023,gid=9997,mask=18 0 0
u0_a238@localhost  ~ #

yes, mount/remount usually requires elevated privileges
